# PowerShell, how to handle a page timeout from an Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: powershell, connection-timeout, invoke-webrequest

I found that a site that I wanted to parse was down today when I went there to download a file.

The code I ran is:

```
$url = "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads"
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -UseBasicParsing
```

How can I intercept and handle this?

- Is there a way to gracefully time out my request after 2 seconds if it does not get a response (which could be from the site being down or from my own internet having problems)?
- What might be the best way to detect if what was returned is "connection timeout junk" as opposed to useful data that I can work with?

[image: output from Invoke-WebRequest]

```
$url = "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads"   # Final url will be like: # https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.6/npp.8.4.6.portable.x64.zip
try {
    $page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3
}
catch { 
    if ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode -band 522) { "bad!"}
}
```

Comment: a `try / catch` checking `if($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode -band 522) { <# do something #>}` ?

Comment: Thanks, trying that out, but not very sure of myself. I put my (very bad) attempt into the OP. I see that the site is still down, so I can test against it.

Comment: you want `-ea Stop` not `-ea silent`. As for timeout, `Invoke-WebRequest` has a `-TimeoutSec` parameter.

Comment: Great, nearly there I think. Problem is that I never seem to get into the `catch` as I'm stopping it after 3 seconds. How do I tell the script to assume that it is an error if it stopped after 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just call the current default error variable exception message/detail.

```
$url = "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads"   
try {$page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3 -ErrorAction Stop}
catch {$Error[0].Exception}
# Results
<#
The operation has timed out.
#>

$url = "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads"   
try {$page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop}
catch {$Error[0].Exception}
# Results
<#
The remote server returned an error: (522).
#>
```

Thus do what you want based on that error message.

```
$url = "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads"   
try {$page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop}
catch
{
    If (($Error[0].Exception) -match '522')
    {Write-Warning  -Message 'Bad stuff happened. Now, go do stuff'}
}
# Results
<#
WARNING: Bad stuff happened. Now, go do stuff
#>
```

***Update***

Timeout check.

```
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$url = "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads"   
try {$page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 3 -ErrorAction Stop}
catch 
{
    $Error[0].Exception
    
    If (($Error[0].Exception) -match 'timed out')
    {Write-Warning  -Message 'Timeout occurred. Do you want to set a differnet timeout'}
}
$timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
# Results
<#
The operation has timed out.
WARNING: Timeout occurred. Do you want to set a differnet timeout
3.0225485
#>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm finding one problem - if I use `-Timeoutsec 3`, the script acts as if there was no failure, and therefore the `catch` does not happen. How can I instruct the script to interpret a timeout to be an error (otherwise, it takes about 10-15 seconds to timeout!)?

Comment: I don't follow. What script is not firing? The catch is firing as shown in my update for you.

Comment: If I remove the `-TimeoutSec 3`, the `Invoke-WebRequest` times out perfectly and the `catch` happens (exactly as you showed). However, if I put the `-Timeoutsec 3` switch back into the command, the `Invoke-WebRequest` gracefully times out at 3 seconds, and so the `catch` is never entered. The point being that in the script, if the `-TimeoutSec` is removed, the error can take 10 to 15 seconds to generate, which is too long. If it is successful, it takes ~0.5 sec, so a timeout of 3 seconds is sufficient to know. How can I use `-TimeoutSec 3` **and** for that to fire the `catch`?

Comment: That is not what I am seeing on my systems. As per the .Net timer, I am using to quantify the timespan of execution.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the update, checking now, thanks. EDIT: Checked it now, that's great, it works perfectly. Many thanks, this is very useful for me.

Comment: No worries, Gald it helped.